# How can you change the "inherit rotation, scale location" for a vertex or empty or an object, not just a bone?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, transforms

When you parent bones to bones, you have options of inheriting rotation, scale and location. But, I don't see those options when I do things like parent an object to an empty or an empty to a vertex. Where are these options?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option. Objects always inherit their parent's transformation. You can use constraints to selectively copy transformations from other objects to work around this, though.

Comment: There is no direct option, but you could imitate the same behavior using animation nodes

Comment: Using constraints would be better, as it doesn't need any external add-on. I've updated my answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just to amplify @dr. 's answer, the 'Child Of' constraint gives Object parenting behaviour, with options for each of the basic transforms, in each of the axes.

The 'Copy *XXX*' constraints give more options: how to combine the target's transforms with the owner's existing ones, and in which space the copied transforms are evaluated.